# R load script objects to workspace

Tags: r, object, workspace

This is a rookie question that I cannot seem to figure out.  Say you've built an R script that manipulates a few data frames.  You run the script, it prints out the result.  All is well.  How is it possible to load objects created within the script to be used in the workspace?  For example, say the script creates data frame df1.  How can we access that in the workspace?  Thanks.

Here is the script...simple function just reads a csv file and computes diff between columns 2 and 3...basically I would like to access spdat in workspace

```
mspreaddata<-function(filename){

# read csv file
rdat<-read.csv(filename,header=T,sep=",")


# compute spread value column 2-3
spdat$sp<-rdat[,2]-rdat[,3]
}
```

Comment: Can you please include a simplified example script?

Answer (score 26):

You should use the `source` function.

i.e. use `source("script.R")`

EDIT:

Check the documentation for further details.  It'll run the script you call. The objects will then be in your workspace.

Alternatively you can save those objects using `save` and then load them using `load`.

Comment: yes I am sourcing the function and running it...script runs the function but for some reason the data files are not loading to workspace.

Comment: Then you need to show us a reproducible example.  It's possible the objects you are creating are temporary and not in the proper environment.

Comment: ok posted the sample function above...question is how can I access the "spdat" function that is created

Comment: So when you source that, the function mspreaddata is not available in your workspace?

Comment: FYI I am using RStudio.  The function name comes up in the workspace, but none of the data frames created using the function are loaded.  I tried a few other sample functions, and the same is occurring.  This is not normal correct?

Comment: Please see my new answer.  If this is still not working for you, are you getting an error message?  It's possible you have an error in your code.  I have just done this and it works fine in rstudio for me.

Answer (score 1):

So when you source that, the function `mspreaddata` is not available in your workspace?  Because in there `spdat` is never created.  You are just creating a function and not running it.  That object `spdat` only exists within that function and not in any environment external to that.  You should add something like

```
newObject <- mspreaddata("filename.csv")
```

Then you can access `newObject`

EDIT:

It is also the case that `spdat` is not created in your function so the call to `spdat$sp<-rdat[,2]-rdat[,3]` is itself incorrect.  Simply use `return(rdat[,2]-rdat[,3])` instead.

Comment: I see thanks, so objects in the function are local to the function, and one needs to invoke return to specifically on and objects to make them available.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yup!  Feel free to upvote and select it as answer ;)